# How to set attribute of SVG child element?

Tags: javascript, svg

For simplicity sake, assume the following:

```
<svg id="node">
 <g id="reg">
   <!--Path data-->
 </g>
 <g id="expanded">
   <!--Path data-->
 </g>
</svg>
```

This is the general scheme of my code, some `svg` attributes are left out for readability sake.

> Problem: I can access and modify the "node" element using `getElementById("node")` , but if i try to access the children of node via childNodes or via direct id , or via `getElementsByTagName` it seems to give me a clone element that is not actually in the DOM. I say this cause any changes i make to the child lements are not reflected on the screen.

How do i fix this, Thank you  ?

Comment: We need more info. Please provide a [MCVE]. Your problem could be one of several things.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `setAttribute` for that!

You can find the elements by `id`.

```
var element = document.getElementById("reg");
element.setAttribute("fill", "white");
```

Or you can use help classes fot that. So apply classes to your paths like

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("node");
var child1 = element.getElementsByClassName("reg");
child1.setAttribute("fill", "white");
```

and if you are able to use jQuery it's really easy:

```
$("svg").find("g");
```

Comment: SVG `<g>` elements have no explicit width.

Comment: I'm sorry but actually i cant...see edit for more info.